# replace two consecutive spaces with one space in c

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I replace multiple spaces with a single space in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217721/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c)

I have a string in c that can contain two consecutive spaces. I want to remove two consecutive spaces with one space. How can I do that? Help please.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/779875/772653 .

Comment: Is there a only one occurrence of two consecutive spaces in the string?

Answer (score 2):

If it is the case that there is a single occurrence of two consecutive spaces in the string then a possibility would be to use `strstr()` and `memmove()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "a string with two  spaces";
    char* two_spaces_ptr = strstr(s, "  ");
    printf("[%s]\n", s);
    if (two_spaces_ptr)
    {
        memmove(two_spaces_ptr + 1,
                two_spaces_ptr + 2,
                strlen(two_spaces_ptr + 2) + 1); /* +1 to copy the NULL. */

    }
    printf("[%s]\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[a string with two  spaces]
[a string with two spaces]
```

The C standard for `memmove()` states:

> The memmove function copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 into the
>   object pointed to by s1. Copying takes place as if the n characters from the object
>   pointed to by s2 are first copied into a temporary array of n characters that does not
>   overlap the objects pointed to by s1 and s2, and then the n characters from the
>   temporary array are copied into the object pointed to by s1.

EDIT:

Updated answer to use `memmove()`, instead of `strcpy()` that resulted in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Good, simple code. And the remark about overlapping memory is important, even though it is not a problem for this particular code.

Comment: And tested here http://ideone.com/PcOlq.

Comment: they definitely overlap and the code produces `[aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa spaces]` on AIX

Comment: @hroptatyr, updated answer to use `memmove()` instead of `strcpy()` to prevent undefined behaviour.

Comment: @pmg, updated answer to use `memmove()` instead of `strcpy()` to prevent undefined behaviour.

Comment: @hmjd: confirmed, works now :)

Comment: `memmove()` is good. Comment about overlapping objects and `strcpy()` removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strchr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strchr.html) function to search for a space in a string and then follow it up with a logic to replace all the spaces following it. You need to repeat this for another patch of spaces till the string ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can write over your own string:

```
char *ys = YOUR_STRING;
char *n = ys;
while (*ys)
{
  *n = *ys;
  if (*ys == ' ')
    while (*ys == ' ')
      ys++;
  else
    ys++;
  n++;
}
```

Or you can create a new string:

```
char *ys = YOUR_STRING;
char *n = malloc(sizeof(*n) * strlen(ys));
int i = 0;

while (*ys)
{
  n[i++] = *ys;
  if (*ys == ' ')
    while (*ys == ' ')
      ys++;
  else
    ys++;
}
// use n
```

Comment: No, you don't necessarily need to create a new one, even though it can improve readability and make the code more generic.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (unsigned char *p = YOUR_STRING, *q = p; ((*q = *p));) {
        if (*q++ == ' ') {
                while (*++p == ' ');
        } else {
                p++;
        }
}
```

Less obscure alternative:

```
unsigned char *p = YOUR_STRING;
unsigned char *q;
/* zap to the first occurrence */
while (*p && *p++ != ' ');
/* copy from here */
q = --p;
while ((*q = *p)) {
        if (*q++ == ' ') {
                while (*++p == ' ');
        } else {
                p++;
        }
}
```

Comment: You don't replace anything, at least put a `//use *p char here` comment after your `if/else`. Anyway this does not work as `q` will pass on the spaces after the first one and cause your `while` to increment `p` at least once even if `*p` is not a space, you will have a difference between `*q` and `*p`.

Comment: huh?  `p` and `q` are just temporary pointers, `YOUR_STRING` is modified by side-effect

Comment: no... it's not modified by a side effect, you are not assigning anything you are just incrementing your _pointers_ here. If you want to remove spaces you have to allocate a new string and copy only one space, moving on top of others

Comment: @Eregrith: And yes of course there's a difference between `q` and `p`, `p` traverses the string while `q` builds up the string with only a single space

Comment: @Eregrith, well try the code and see the magic :)

Comment: the assignment is in the condition part of the `for`-loop

Comment: This is a horribly obscure way to solve this trivial task, if it even does what you claim it does.

Comment: Ok I see where i was wrong. Why on earth did you put the assignment `*q = *p` __IN THE FOR'S CONDITION ZONE__ ?????

Comment: @Lundin: well I disagree, I think it's beautiful because all pointers only increment and so the whole operation can be done using just 2 registers

Comment: complete abuse of the for loop. the progression zone is empty, the condition does 2 things... copy from p to q and test if copied value was different of \0... you win the obscurity test hands down

Comment: Not that it matters, but I chose the `for` loop to introduce `q` and `p` only.  Nobody would have objected the corresponding `while ((*q = *p))` form.

Comment: @hroptatyr It is ugly as can be and premature optimization. Look at hmjd's code in comparison. An optimized compiler would inline the strstr and strcpy calls, resulting in pretty much identical code. Well, not exactly identical as his code is generic, while this code is not. In the end, readability is far more valuable than performance in 99.9% of all programs.

Comment: As a curiousity, this little code alone yielded 15 violations of the MISRA-C coding standard when executed in a static code analyser (LDRA Testbed).

Comment: @Lundin: Except that hmjd's solution didn't work.  See my less obscure variant.

Answer (score -1):

If you're sure there can be only two spaces consecutive at max, you can do something like:

```
int main ()
{
    char *str="This  is a  wonderful world. Let's  have a   good  time here.";
    int len=strlen(str);
    char *result = (char*)malloc(len);
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
        if(str[i]==' ' && str[i-1]==' ') {
            i++;
        }
        result[j++]=str[i];
    }
    result[j]='\0';
    printf("%s\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 for teaching to typecast the result of malloc. Please remove the typecast. Read [this](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: -1 for buggy code example, evidently untested.

Comment: @Eregrith Fixed. Lundin, Thanks. So far, I was always told to put the typecast. :-). Paul, Fixed.

Comment: There are still serious bugs in the code, e.g. look at what happens if the first character in the string is a space.