# How do escape sequences actually behave in the scanf() function

Tags: c, scanf

I've looked through some stuff to find out, but nothing proper has been found (or I am a bad searcher though).

Now I'm learning the scanf function from stdio.h header, and they say escape sequences are not recommended here because it 'confuses' the input, but what actually happens? I tested some code out and got results for differens ES:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c;

    printf("Enter values: \n");
    scanf("%d%d%d\n", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("The values are %d, %d and %d.\n", a, b, c);
}

Enter values: 
1
2
3
randomstuff
The values are 1, 2 and 3.
```

The same is with '\t' sequence – it asks for one more value (I typed 'randomstuff') which is not stored anywhere.
'\a' and '\b', on the other hand, behave differently and does not affect the input:

```
    ...
    scanf("%d%d%d\a", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("The values are %d, %d and %d.\n", a, b, c);
}

Enter values: 
1
2
3
The values are 1, 2 and 3.
```

It becomes more confusing when I mess around with the position of the ES. '\n' and '\t' stop affecting the input:

```
    ...
    scanf("%d\t%d\n%d", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("The values are %d, %d and %d.\n", a, b, c);
}

Enter values: 
1
2
3
The values are 1, 2 and 3.
```

whereas '\a' and '\b' start having some influence:

```
    ...
    scanf("%d\b%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("The values are %d, %d and %d.\n", a, b, c);
}

Enter values: 
1    
The values are 1, 0 and 32766.
```

Some say ES are not interpreted by scanf() and are simply taken as plain characters, but that does not seem true as well since it does interpret such ES like \' or \" in accordance with the rules.

So what is going on?
PS and why is there 0 and 32766 in the last outcome?

Comment: `if (scanf("%d\b%d%d", &a, &b, &c) != 3) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: Escape sequences are just characters, and `scanf`() handles them just like any other character.

Comment: `scanf`'s [Format Specification Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-fields-scanf-and-wscanf-functions?view=vs-2019) says "*White-space characters: blank (' '); tab ('\t'); or newline ('\n'). A white-space character causes scanf to read, but not store, all consecutive white-space characters in the input up to the next non-white-space character. One white-space character in the format matches any number (including 0) and combination of white-space characters in the input.*"

Comment: ...but as format specifiers `%d` and `%f` and `%s` automatically filter leading whitespace, there is no need to explicitly filter it. It is  `%c` and `%[...]` (and `%n`) that do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `scanf` receives a string, there are no escape sequences in it. If a string literal was used as an argument, the escape sequences in it were processed when the program was translated (compiled). C 2018 6.4.4.4 specifies how escape sequences are processed:

- `\'`, `\"`, `\?`, and `\\` become `'`, `"`, `?`, and `\`, respectively.
- `\a`, `\b`, `\f`, `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, and `\v` become characters for alert, backspace, formfeed, new line, carriage return, horizontal tab, and vertical tab, respectively.
- `\d`, `\dd`, and `\ddd`, where each `d` is an octal digit, become the character with that value.
- `\x` followed by one or more hexadecimal digits becomes the character with that value.

Then for `scanf`, the characters have meanings:

- If the character is a white-space character (space, horizontal tab, new line, vertical tab, formfeed), it directs `scanf` to read input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread) or until no more characters can be read.
- If the character is `%` (which can result from an octal or hexadecimal escape sequence), it introduces a conversion specification, such as `%d`.
- Otherwise, it directs `scanf` to read the next character and match it literally (an alert character in the format string must match an alert character in the input stream, and so on).

> The same is with '\t' sequence – it asks for one more value (I typed 'randomstuff') which is not stored anywhere.

`\t` in a string literal becomes a (horizontal) tab, and a tab character is a white-space character, so it directs `scanf` to read input until it sees a white-space character or cannot get more input. This is why, when you added `\t`, `scanf` kept reading until it saw the non-white-space character “r” of your “randomstuff”.

> '\a' and '\b', on the other hand, behave differently and does not affect the input:

These are not white-space characters and are not `%`, so they direct `scanf` to attempt to match them literally with characters in the input stream. For `"%d%d%d\a"`, `scanf` matched the three `%d` specifications, and then it read one more character to attempt to match it to the alert character. That failed, so `scanf` stopped and returned 3 for the three successful matches. (`scanf` also “put back” the non-matching character into the input stream.)

> It becomes more confusing when I mess around with the position of the ES. '\n' and '\t' stop affecting the input:

In `"%d\t%d\n%d"`, the tab and new line characters direct `scanf` to match white-space characters. However, these are already normally skipped by `scanf` as part of the `%d` conversion specification, so they have no effect before `%d`.

> whereas '\a' and '\b' start having some influence:

With `"%d\b%d%d"`, the first decimal numeral is processed, and then the backspace directs `scanf` to match a backspace character. Since there is no backspace character in the input, matching fails, and `scanf` stops.

Note that none of these behaviors involve `scanf` processing escape sequences. `scanf` is processing the characters it receives, which are the characters such as tab, alert, and backspace. It does not see the original escape sequences.

Comment: That's not quite clear yet though... As far as I could get that, when I press 'enter' with a white-space char at the end of the line, instead of confirming my last value it reads that last char which is \n or \t, doesn't it? But when \n or \t is followed by another %d (%f, %u, whatever, may be apart from %c), input confirmation takes priority over char reading, since, as you said, following % makes \n be skipped, does it? this last point now is the dimmest for me... As for \a (\b), it makes sense now, the input waits for a user to give \a or \b, even though there is no way to do that, right?

Answer (score 2):

As I commented above, whitespace characters in the `scanf` format string remove one or more whitespace characters from the input. But `\b` is not a whitespace character and therefore has to be matched in the input. If you had made the *essential* check of the value returned by `scanf`, which here should be `3` (the number of items converted), you would have seen that the values were not all read.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, r;
    r = scanf("%d\b%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("return val = %d\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

Program session:

```
7 8 9
return val = 1
```

This is why you have strange output: values have not been assigned to `b` and `c`.