# How to replace spans of whitespace with a single space in a C string?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function that turns all spans of whitespace (i.e multiple spaces, a newline, a tab, or any continuous sequence of the aforementioned) into a single space.

For example, the following inputs:

```
"example\tinput\tstring"
"example\ninput\nstring"
"example  \tinput \n string"
```

Would all result in the same output:
    "example input string"

I currently have the following code based on a similar question here on Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1217750/6652030, the 2nd answer). It handles sequences of multiple spaces correctly, but it doesn't replace tabs and newlines with spaces as intended. If I pass the first two example inputs, my resulting string is "exampleinputstring". Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

```
void removeExtraWhitespace(char *src, char *dst) {
  for (; *src; ++dst, ++src) {
    *dst = *src;
    if (*src == '\n' || *src == '\t') {
      *src = ' ';
    }

    else if (isspace(*src)) {
      while (!isspace(*(src + 1))) {
        ++src;
      }
    }
  }

  *dst = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Do you want leading white space squished to a single space or omitted?  What about trailing white space?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Leading and trailing whitespace should be squished to a single space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to replace spans of whitespace with a single space in a C string?

Simply keep track of the previous action and test for whitespace.  Only 1 tight loop needed, one call to `isspace()`.  This also handles leading/trailing whitespace.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void removeExtraWhitespace(const char *src, char *dst) {
  bool previous_was_whitespace = false;
  while (*src) {
    if (isspace((unsigned char) *src)) {
      if (!previous_was_whitespace) {
        *dst++ = ' ';
      }
      previous_was_whitespace = true;
    } else {
      *dst++ = *src;
      previous_was_whitespace = false;
    }
    src++;
  }
  *dst = '\0';
}
```

> Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

When OP's code first encounters a `'\n'`, `'\t'`, it changes `src[]`, but that never effect `dst[]`.

Also drop the `else` in the below code.  This allows consumption of consecutive whitespace after `'\n'`, `'\t'`. Yet this still has trouble other white-spaces such as `'\r'`.

```
if (*src == '\n' || *src == '\t') {
  *src = ' ';
}

// else if (isspace(*src)) {
if (isspace(*src)) {
```

---

This code uses `isspace((unsigned char) *src)` rather than `isspace(*src)` as `isspace()` is only defined for values in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`.  With learner programs, it is unusual to encounter negative values for `*src`, yet they can exist and conversion to the `unsigned char` range is prudent.

Comment: Thank you! This did the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the following modification to your code:

```
void removeExtraWhitespace(char *dst, const char *src) {
  for(; *src; ++dst, ++src) {
    if (isspace(*src)) {
      *dst = ' ';
      while (isspace(*(src + 1))) {
        ++src;
      }
    } else {
      *dst = *src;
    }
  }
  *dst = '\0';
}
```

For example,

```
char dst[50];
$ removeExtraWhitespace(dst, "\t\t\texample\t\t\n    input\nstring\n\n   ");
$ printf("%s\n", dst);
 example input string
```

Comment: `if (*src == '\t' || *src == '\n') ...  else if (isspace(*src)) ` is a bit weird. `isspace` checks for any white space characters, including `'\t'`, `'\n'` and `' '`.

Comment: `removeExtraWhitespace(dst, "123\t\t456");` --> `"<123  456>"`  (2 spaces between 3 and 4)

Comment: Thanks! @Lundin, I've collapsed the `if ... else if` conditions into one, using `isspace` for whitespace checking. @chux, I've fixed the issue by replacing  `*dst = *src;` with `*dst = ' ';`.

Answer (score 0):

In essence you are copying a string into a new place while collapsing all the whitespace (and newline) characters into a single character (if I understood you correctly).

While you are copying over you have three possible "modes of operation":

1. No whitespace (straight copy)
2. "Whitespace" mode - you have encountered a whitespace character and are currently skipping till you see a non-whitespace again
3. You are done skipping the whitespaces and going back to "straight copy" mode

Putting that into pseudocode, this looks like the following:

```
bool skipping = false;
for(each char){
  if(iswhite(char)){
    skipping = true;
    continue; // next source char
  }
  // not a whitespace, let's see if we are done skipping
  if(skipping){
    // collapse all those skipped whitespaces into one
    copy_space_into_dest;
  }
  skipping = false;
  copy_char_into_dest;
}
```

The `iswhite()` above could be a call to `isspace()` or your own function that will return `true` for anything it considers to be a white space (for example if you decide that a `_` is a "white space")

Comment: This trims out all leading white-space, yet compresses trailing whitespace into a single space.

Answer (score 0):

The code I came up with for the problem was:

```
static
void removeExtraWhiteSpace(char *src, char *dst)
{
    while (*src != '\0')
    {
        if (!isspace((unsigned char)*src))
            *dst++ = *src++;
        else
        {
            *dst++ = ' ';
            while (isspace((unsigned char)*src))
                src++;
        }
    }
    *dst = '\0';
}
```

For each character, if it isn't a space according to `isspace()` from `<ctype.h>`, copy it to the output.  If it is a space, copy a space to the output, and skip over any following space characters.  When finished, add the null terminator.

The function is `static` because I make all functions `static` unless there's a header that declares the function for use in other files — the compilation options I use require this discipline (or a prior `extern void removeExtraWhiteSpace(char *src, char *dst)` declaration for the function — but `static` is shorter.

If you want to remove leading and trailing blanks, it isn't much harder:

```
static
void removeExtraWhiteSpace(char *src, char *dst)
{
    char *tgt = dst;
    while (isspace((unsigned char)*src))
        src++;
    while (*src != '\0')
    {
        if (!isspace((unsigned char)*src))
            *tgt++ = *src++;
        else
        {
            *tgt++ = ' ';
            while (isspace((unsigned char)*src))
                src++;
        }
    }
    *tgt = '\0';
    if (tgt > dst && tgt[-1] == ' ')
        tgt[-1] = '\0';
}
```

Test code:

```
static void test_string(char *buffer1)
{
    printf("Before [%s]\n", buffer1);
    char buffer2[1024];
    removeExtraWhiteSpace(buffer1, buffer2);
    printf("After  [%s]\n", buffer2);
}

int main(void)
{
    test_string("example\tinput\tstring");
    test_string("example\ninput\nstring");
    test_string("example  \tinput \n string");
    test_string("  \t spaces\t \tand tabs\tboth  before\t\tand  \t \t after  \t\t ");

#ifdef GO_INTERACTIVE
    char buffer[1024];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0)
    {
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
        test_string(buffer);
    }
#endif /* GO_INTERACTIVE */

    return 0;
}
```

Plain output:

```
Before [example input   string]
After  [example input string]
Before [example
input
string]
After  [example input string]
Before [example     input 
 string]
After  [example input string]
Before [     spaces     and tabs    both  before        and          after           ]
After  [ spaces and tabs both before and after ]
```

With tabs and newlines marked (^I for tabs, ^J for newlines):

```
Before [example^Iinput^Istring]^J
After  [example input string]^J
Before [example^J
input^J
string]^J
After  [example input string]^J
Before [example  ^Iinput ^J
 string]^J
After  [example input string]^J
Before [  ^I spaces^I ^Iand tabs^Iboth  before^I^Iand  ^I ^I after  ^I^I ]^J
After  [ spaces and tabs both before and after ]^J
```